# Unterminated string constant

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net

I have an edit linkbutton where I click and it brings a pop up dialog with the text to edit. When I edit the text and submit it works fine. but if I include an "Enter/Return" space in editing then I can't edit again. So I would like assistance in this regard. I have a js function I call on the C# side on clicking the edit linkbutton. When I look in the developer dashboard I see the error as Unterminated string constant. But it's not giving me much to work with. I checked the string if they are properly closed with matching quotes etc.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding/escaping the string in JavaScript with `escape("your string")` before submitting.